# How to test if an `NSObject` has a property with arbitrary name that can be set?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsobject

I want to implement a generic populating of a model from a dictionary. I test if the model has a property using a following test, but the condition always fails:

```
if (self.responds(to:(NSSelectorFromString(keyName)))){
    self.setValue(keyValue, forKey: key )
}
```

Here is an example code:

```
import UIKit

class myModel: NSObject {    
    var userName: String = ""
    var phoneNumber: String = ""

    init(dict: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        super.init()

        for (key, value) in dict {
            let keyName = key     
            let keyValue: String = String(describing: value)

            print("key \(key) value \(value)")

            if (self.responds(to:(NSSelectorFromString(keyName)))){
                self.setValue(keyValue, forKey: key )
            }
        }          
    }        
}
```

Comment: please check i have edited my question

Comment: @Sandip: Are you asking how to set model value from dictionary right?

Comment: yes i want to add values from my dictionary to model

Comment: what swift version do you use? `Dictionary` is generic, you don't set its generic type

Comment: swift version 4.0

Comment: @clemens this is my value corresponding to my value

Comment: Use the `Codable` protocol. It's much better than this ugly KVC syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost done. Add the following at top of your NSObject class - `@objcMembers`

Such as -

```
import UIKit

@objcMembers

class myModel: NSObject {
```

Comment: what's benefit to make it generic? I don't think this is good way to do it you have to write same boilerplate code again and again

Comment: setvalue of NSobject is written by Objective-C, so to make all key of NSobject declare in Swift available to Objective-C function, We have to add @objcMembers keyword, [read more link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objcmembers-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

This works as you expect (tested in playgrounds):

```
import UIKit

class myModel: NSObject {
    @objc var userName: String = ""
    @objc var phoneNumber: String = ""

    init(dict: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        super.init()

        for (key, value) in dict {
            let keyCapitalized = key.prefix(1).uppercased() + key.dropFirst()

            let keyName = "set\(keyCapitalized):"
            let keyValue: String = String(describing: value)

            print("key \(key) (selector: '\(keyName))' value \(value)")

            if self.responds(to: Selector(keyName)) {
                self.setValue(keyValue, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}

let m = myModel(dict: ["userName" : "milan", "data" : "data"])
print(">>> \(m.userName)") // prints ">>> milan"
print(">>> \(m.phoneNumber)") // prints ">>> " (number was not provided, and data key was ignored)
```

Just two points.

First of all, you need to expose those properties to ObjectiveC for `responds()` to work - therefore I added `@objc` annotations on both properties.

Second of all, the proper selector syntax to test if you can set the property named `userName` is NOT `Selector("userName")`, but `Selector("setUserName:")` (you are testing a setter).

Comment: just dictionary parameters are different

Comment: these are my dictionary values :-  

["groups": <null>, "data": , "source": Flexstat2V0RSTDAwMDAwMQ, "serial": 1, "relayID": WDRL000001, "category": event, "type": reachable, "timestamp": 1510965150402]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162986/discussion-between-sandip-gill-and-milan-nosa).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries need to be given a *type* for their keys and values. What you have in your initialiser is too ambiguous.

Because the result of getting something out of a dictionary can be nil, you need to provide a default value which is what happens after `??`

```
class MyModel: NSObject {

    var userName: String = ""
    var phoneNumber: String = ""

    init(dict: [String : String]) {
        self.userName = dict["userName"] ?? ""
        self.phoneNumber = dict["phoneNumber"] ?? ""
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm that's not really the conventional way of writing Swift and is prone to error, which is what Swift tries to avoid as a language.

Comment: i have some null values in it

Comment: Null values will be `nil` and you can provide default values with `??` which is what I'm dong above. Swift is designed to handle this well.

Comment: there might be some null value of any dictionary

Comment: so you can call let myModel = MyModel(dict:nil) there might be some scenario dict may nil

Comment: "There might be some null value of any dictionary": which is why `??` provides a default value
"There might be some scenario dict may nil`: not according to the original question, because the argument is not optional. Don't over complicate the code for no reason.

Comment: let consider you are getting JSON dictionary and your dictionary is null then the code will not be able to handle it

Comment: you should use optional as it has wide usage like optional chaining and other as I asked it's best practice.

Comment: It's not best practice to have all properties as optional at all.

Answer (score 0):

Below way you can set model values from a dictionary.

```
class MyModel {
    var userName: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?

    init(dict: [String:Any]?) {
        self.userName = dict?["username"] as? String
        self.phoneNumber = dict?["phonenumber"] as? String
    }
}
```

Example Usage :

```
let myModel = MyModel(dict: ["username":"test","phonenumber":"1234567890"])
```

Comment: This is assuming `userName` can be `nil`, which it isn't in the original question :)

Comment: I think best practice Model property should be optional. In view, while  displaying data in view it will be decided to display blank or any other thing.

Comment: I disagree, I think the model should be responsible for populating it's own data and the view just displays whatever that data is. If you're using MVVM (view models) then the whole point is to make the view dumb and for the model to contain the logic.

Comment: Also why is `dict` optional? What's the point of creating a model with no data at all? Why not just pass in an empty dictionary in that case? An optional dictionary provides no extra value here and is not what the original question asked for.

Comment: let consider I am displaying same data in 2 different places in one view business want to display blank and another view they want to display "N/A" or something else then?

Comment: That's when a second model would be created that knows how to populate itself with "N/A", which would be used somewhere else. This is over-engineering the model for no reason. Design for the problem at hand, not a problem that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: how? can you give an example?